# jfxtras - CalendarPicker change button color

Tags: javafx, jfxtras

How can I change the color of every toggle button of a CalendarPicker?
For instance, one button "red", one button "yellow" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to, if you can create a CSS rule for it. The toggle buttons are just toggle buttons, so they have the same CSS styleable features. So a "#mypicker .toggle-button" css rule should select them.

However, selecting individual buttons would require the use of something like "nth-child", but I believe JavaFX does not support that. There is a backdoor; the day togglebuttons get an id assigned, "day0", "day1", ... This is irrespective of whether the button is hidden or not. 
https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/8.0/jfxtras-controls/src/main/java/jfxtras/internal/scene/control/skin/CalendarPickerControlSkin.java line 366

But this is a shaky dependency. If you have a good use case, I can of course assign a special unique style class to each button.

Comment: How can i get an individual togglebutton from the CalendarPicker? The dayButtons are private and i cannot find a Getter-Method

Comment: The use case is: Colour every day of the calendar which depends of the type of day (e.g. weekday, weekend, public holiday, private holiday, birthday, etc.). Each togglebutton needs a type and a color.

Comment: You cannot get to the buttons, that would be exposing the skin to the outside. This is not how controls in JavaFX should work.

Comment: About your use case; what when two types are happening on the same day, for example a holiday and birthday)? I think you are describing whole day appointments in JFXtras' Agenda control.

Comment: With your answer i resolve it. Each togglebutton-node of the CalendarPicker has an named ID. The invisible ones "day0"-"dayX" and the visible ones like "2015-04-30". With colorpicker.lookup("2015-04-30") i can found the node of the togglebutton and change the style with node.setStyle("-fx-base: <RGBColor>").